# Apply function to all even values in data frame

Tags: r

`df <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:5, rep(10), ncol = 10))`

This is my example data frame.
I'd like to apply the following to all even values: take -6 and then compute the absolute value.

The result should look like that:

```
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
2   4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4   4
3   3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3   3
4   2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2   2
5   5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5   5
6   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
7   4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4   4
8   3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3   3
9   2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2   2
10  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5   5
```

You could also say replace all the 2s by 4s and vice versa....

I tried to filter() out all the evens and then do -6 and abs(), tried a for loop as well and an if else function... It didn't work out the way I wanted and got far too complicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could directly apply the function as these are vectorized

```
df[!df %%2] <- abs(df[!df %%2]-6)
```

-output

```
> df
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
2   4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4   4
3   3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3   3
4   2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2   2
5   5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5   5
6   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
7   4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4   4
8   3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3   3
9   2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2   2
10  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5   5
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ifelse` inside an `lapply`, and write the resultant list back into the data frame:

```r
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:5, rep(10), ncol = 10))

df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) ifelse(x %% 2 == 0, abs(x - 6), x))

df
#>    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
#> 1   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
#> 2   4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4   4
#> 3   3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3   3
#> 4   2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2   2
#> 5   5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5   5
#> 6   1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1
#> 7   4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4   4
#> 8   3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3   3
#> 9   2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2   2
#> 10  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5   5
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>